# AppleScript Login And Upload To Dropbox

Tags: upload, applescript, dropbox

Ok, so I am trying to log into dropbox.com using AppleScript and upload a folder and files.

I am at the very beginning stages of this thing (and i'm a super beginner to applescript) so bear with me...

This is the script that I have so far:

```
set theEmail to "fakeemail@email.com"
set thePassword to "fakePassword"

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "https://www.dropbox.com/home"

    tell application "System Events"
        delay 3
        keystroke tab
        keystroke tab
        keystroke tab
        keystroke theEmail
        keystroke tab
        keystroke thePassword
        delay 1
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

2 things:

1. I am having problems when I am already logged into dropbox because it starts to put in my credentials because it thinks I'm not already logged in. Please help with that... :)
2. I have no idea where to even start with telling applescript that I want to upload a folder and files to dropbox. So I REALLY need help with that.

This is going to be used for a nightly backup script.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox has an API. I'd strongly suggest using that: https://www.dropbox.com/developers.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to install the Dropbox app on your system. Dropbox behaves like a local volume then and is accessible for the Finder. Everything you write into it will be synced in the background automatically.

With this in mind your problem is to copy files into a directory only...

Comment: I would love to use the Dropbox Desktop App because it would be easy, but the reason why I don't is because it will become too tedious to change the "Selective Sync" on it each night to show the current day. This is a work project and I work at a busy photography studio that will be backing up photos to dropbox nightly. I would not like to do it manually and then manually check off Dropbox's Selective Sync feature each day. This is why I thought that AppleScript would be the best way. (Also because it is easy and Im very new to the whole scripting thing. Thanks for the thoughts! More thoughts?

Comment: @jimgymjaroo So if you had a folder in dropbox named Photo_Backups and placed your daily folders in that. Then I would assume you would then only need to select the Photo_Backups folder once in Selective sync and all the sub folders and file would be backed up?